# Input не переключается в активное состояние

Tags: html, css

Кастомизирую инпут-чекбокс, но что-то упускаю и он как-будто не переключается в состояние "checked"

```css
.publications {
  padding: 80px 0;
  background: #cacaca;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
  max-width: 1700px;
}

.publications__input:checked,
.publications__input:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.publications__input:checked+.publications__label,
.publications__input:not(:checked)+.publications__label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 28px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.publications__input:checked+.publications__label:before,
.publications__input:not(:checked)+.publications__label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.publications__input:checked+.publications__label:before,
.publications__input:not(:checked)+.publications__label:before {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.publications__input:checked+.publications__label:after,
.publications__input:not(:checked)+.publications__label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.publications__input:checked+.publications__label:after,
.publications__input:not(:checked)+.publications__label:after {
  left: 3px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-left: 4px solid #e145a3;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #e145a3;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.publications__input:not(:checked)+.publications__label:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.publications__input:checked+.publications__label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="publications">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="subheading white-font">Издания</h2>
    <h3>Категории</h3>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-bestsellers">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-bestsellers">Бестселлеры</label>
    </div>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-art">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-art">Искусство</label>
    </div>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-architecture">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-architecture">Архитектура</label>
    </div>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-design">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-design">Дизайн</label>
    </div>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-fashion">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-fashion">Мода</label>
    </div>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-for-kids">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-for-kids">Детям</label>
    </div>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-fiction">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-fiction">Художественная литература</label>
    </div>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-journalism">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-journalism">Публицистика</label>
    </div>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-travel-guides">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-travel-guides">Путеводители</label>
    </div>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-philosophy">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-philosophy">Философия</label>
    </div>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-manual">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-manual">Учебная литература</label>
    </div>
    <div class="publications__input-inner">
      <input class="publications__input" type="checkbox" name="" id="input-newspapers">
      <label class="publications__label" for="input-newspapers">Журналы и газеты</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: а что именно "не переключается"? в примере всё работает - галочка появляется и исчезает.

Comment: здесь в песочгице все работает, в браузере не работает, ctrl+f5 не помогает

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <input ... id="input-bestsellers"
> <label ... for="input-architecture"
> ```

А с чего бы ему переключаться?

Comment: Ок, поправлю сниппет для более полной картины)

Comment: Ну ок, эти ошибку я исправил, а в браузере все равно не переключаются)

Comment: А в сниппете переключается. [Mcve]?